# Google App Script GET not returning readable response

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, fetch

I have a Google Script that is called with a GET containing a google drive file id and returns the name of the file.

```
function  doGet(e){
 var id = e.parameter.id
 var fname = getFileName(id);

 logData('getFileName', id, fname)
 return ContentService.createTextOutput(fname);
}
```

I call this script from a web app deployed using NPM.

```
partRoutes.post('/docs', (req, res) => {
    fetch(getReferenceDocs + `?id=${req.body.id}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => res.status(201).send(json))
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err.message) 
        res.sendStatus(500)
      })
  })
```

Up until a month ago this was working, now it fails to return the file name every time.

Logging the result of getFileName shows that it is still returning the proper file name, however the requesting web app does not receive a proper response.

Update:
When I test the Script with Postman I get the expected response of the file name. So The issue must be on how the NPM script is handling the fetch. I have tried several ways to read the response and none seem to work.

Comment: And what sort of errors are occurring when your client is not getting the proper response? If your function encounters an unhandled exception, then you won't `return` anything.

Comment: @John Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, for example, how about these confirmation? 1. Redeploy the Web Apps as new version. 2. Test the Web Apps using curl command. From these results, how about investigating the reason of your issue?